# Bootstrap: overlay loading screen + toggle jumbotron

Tags: javascript, html, css, overlay, loading

Ok so, I've gone through maybe 20 different stackexchange answers to each of these problems, and I still can't solve it, so it's about time I ask and hopefully somebody can point me out of these woods:

I am making a simple website, and I wanted to make like an overlay screen that contains a loading/progress bar, and just progresses over the course of 3 seconds at most before it fades away and reveals the site. I also wanted to add a logo in the middle of it just above the bar. I looked at some video in arabic, but it got out of hand sort of, I didn't know what he was saying, but I thought I could try his code and modify it, but that didn't work either.

Also, I've got a jumbotron in the code I call "jumbotronTwo", and basically what it is supposed to do is that when you click the menu icon and the dropdown menu appears, you click on one of the options, and then the menu should scroll back and the jumbotron should appear. So far I've just been able to make the jumbotron itself and color it, resize it, fill it with text etc., I tried using some javascript and jquery to make it appear and disappear "onclick", but none seemed to work, i'm starting to think maybe it has to do with what libraries I've got?
I have no idea what could be trumping it, so I need somebody to take a look at the code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Twenty Eight Interiors</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Wiredwiki App">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">


    </head>
```

I think these up here are important to show, in case I forgot some library or something so you can point it out. I've got some CSS as well but cut it out, if you need to see it too I can show it. Here's the "meat and potatoes":

```
    <body>
        <!-- jumbotron-->

        <div class="jumbotron" id="jumbotronOne">
            <div class="container text-center">
                <img src="Untitled.png">
            </div>
        </div>

    <!-- Navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" id="my-navbar" style="font-family:Webdings;">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header" id="oneDiv">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" id="iconButton">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
                    </button>

                <a href="" class="navbar-brand"><font color="white">MENU</font></a>
                </div><!-- Navbar Header -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse" align="center">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="firstOne">
                        <li><a href="#" id="designProcess" role="button">Design Process</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="profile">Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="contactInfo">Contact Info</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="list-inline" id="secondOne">
                        <li><a href="#" class="socialicon"><img src="facebook.png" hspace="30"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="socialicon"><img src="twitter.png" hspace="30"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="socialicon"><img src="instagram.png" hspace="30"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div><!-- End Container img src="twitter.png"-->
        </nav><!-- End navbar -->

      <div class="jumbotron" id="jumbotronTwo">
      <div class="container">
      <h2>Headline goes here in one, two or three lines like this</h1>
      <p>...</p>
      </div>
      </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I even had problems with making the javascript work for the glyphicon, I want it to change when I click it, and again; i have no idea what I'm doing wrong, tried lots of potential solutions from stackexchange, but this too seems to point to that it's something else.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this a 'fake' loading bar or are you actually loading something?!?

Comment: A fake one, since there isn't much to load. And I'd imagine it wouldn't be seen for long, the point of it is to look nice. But if you can show me how to make a real one, I'd accept that too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's just a splash page then add a div at the top of your body and wrap your existing page in a div with display:none...

```
<body>
    <div id="loader">
        <h4>Logo and progress bar here...</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="your-page" style="display:none">
        <!--Your existing content here...-->
    </div>
```

Then add a little jquery...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#loader" ).delay(800).fadeOut(400, function(){
        $( "#your-page" ).fadeIn(400);
    });  
});
```

See working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rmc62kex/).

If you want to make animating your progress bar easy then I recommend [this plugin](https://github.com/minddust/bootstrap-progressbar).

For the glyphicon use the following js...

```
$( "#iconButton" ).click(function(){
    $(this).html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-cheeseburger"></span>');
});
```

Obviously replace the cheeseburger with whatever icon you want to use! See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gLmavnyw/) for this bit (without the actual icons but you should get the idea).

Comment: A huge step in the right direction, thank you so much!
I'll wait a little longer for more answers to pop up, since there's more to be answered, but I appreciate this so much!

Comment: @user1770094 Added solution to glyphicon query. I don't really understand what you're describing with the jumbotron part...

Comment: What a relief :D
Is then the reverse(like if I want to make it toggle, so I click it changes and changes back when I click again) made with an if-statement or would it be a bit more complicated?

Comment: I managed to fix the jumbotron toggle too thanks to you, you've really deserved more than the one upvote I could give. Thank you yet again! :D

Comment: @user1770094 More than welcome. Updated the fiddle to show one way to do the toggle (there's quite a few) although it sounds like you managed it yourself already :)

Answer (score 0):

I see you are loading both jQuery 1.11.2 and 2.1.3, which adds additional loading time as well. This is of course not good and I would suggest just using 3.1.1

In that case @DevFox second code would need to be updated as following, since `(document).ready` is not supported anymore.

```
$(function(){
    $( "#loader" ).delay(800).fadeOut(400, function(){
        $( "#your-page" ).fadeIn(400);
    });  
});
```